# Running a python script in the background using child_process (node js)

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, child-process

I have a python script **test.py** on a raspberry pi which needs to be running in the background. Using the CLI, I do this:

```
python test.py &
```

But, how do I do the same using the child_process in node js.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn("python",["/path/to/test.py", "&"]);
```

I have this code and this seems to be not working. Please suggest possible ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `&` (ampersand) in the command line arguments. It is used by shell, not by python.

Use `{detached: true}` option so it will be able to live when your Node process exits:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var p = spawn("python", ["/path/to/test.py"], {detached: true});
```

If you also want to gnore its output, use `{stdio: 'ignore'}`

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var p = spawn("python", ["/path/to/test.py"], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
```

Also, I wouldn't name the variable `process` because it is used by node:

> The process object is a global that provides information about, and
>   control over, the current Node.js process. As a global, it is always
>   available to Node.js applications without using require().

See: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process

### Update

If it still doesn't exit, try adding:

```
p.unref();
```

to your program, where `p` is what is returned by `spawn`:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var p = spawn("python", ["/path/to/test.py"], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
p.unref();
```

### Update 2

Here is an example shell session - how to run it, test if it works and kill it:

```
$ cat parent.js 
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var fs = require("fs");
var p = spawn("sh", ["child.sh"], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
p.unref();
$ cat child.sh 
#!/bin/sh
sleep 60
$ node parent.js 
$ ps x | grep child.sh
11065 ?        Ss     0:00 sh child.sh
11068 pts/28   S+     0:00 grep child.sh
$ kill 11065
$ ps x | grep child.sh
11070 pts/28   S+     0:00 grep child.sh
$
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the variable name. But, using the **detached: true** option doesn't seem to exit the node process. I had to manually stop it using `ctrl+c`.

Comment: @varm have you also tried the `stdio: 'ignore'` option in my second example? Is the example in your question the entire Node program or does it do something else?

Comment: Yes. I have tried `stdio: 'ignore'` option also. Still getting the same result. That's my entire node program.

Comment: @varm If it still doesn't work, try adding `p.unref()` to your program - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. But how do I see this background process and kill it?

Comment: @varm Find it with `ps x | grep test.py` and then see the PID number on the left and use `kill NUMBER` - see my Update 2 in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really be doing that. Processes should be handled by a real process manager.

If you want to run a background process, you should look into how to run services in Raspberry Pi. It depends on the Linux distribution that is being run on the Raspberry Pi ([Upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) (like in Debian) or [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (like in CentOS))

But anyways, quoting an example from [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process):

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for [your edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12865700). I don't know why it was rejected by the Community. I changed it manually to the block quote. Thanks.

Comment: @rsp That is strange. Anyways! ;-)